# Read in tuple of lists from text file as tuple, not string - Python

Tags: python, file, list, text, tuples

I have a text file I would like to read in that contains rows of tuples. Each tuple/row in text is in the form of ('description string', [list of integers 1], [list of integers 2]).  Where the text file might look something like:

('item 1', [1,2,3,4] , [4,3,2,1])
('item 2', [ ] , [4,3,2,1])
('item 3, [1,2] , [ ])

I would like to be able to read each line in from the text file, then place them directly into a function where,

```
function(string, list1, list2)
```

I know that each line is read in as a string, but I need to extract this string some how.  I have been trying to use a string.split(','), but that comes into problems when I hit the lists.  Is there a way to accomplish this or will I have to modify my text files some how?

I also have a text file of a list of tuples that I would like to read in similarly that is in the form of

[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),...]

that may contain any amount of tuples. I would like to read it in a  list and do a for loop for each tuple in the list.  I figure these two will use roughly the same process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about using `eval`?

**EDIT**  See @Ignacio's answer using `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> c = eval("('item 1', [1,2,3,4] , [4,3,2,1])")
>>> c
('item 1', [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1])
```

I would only recommend doing this if you are 100% sure of the contents of the file.

```
>>> def myFunc(myString, myList1, myList2):
...     print myString, myList1, myList2
... 
>>> myFunc(*eval("('item 1', [1,2,3,4] , [4,3,2,1])"))
item 1 [1, 2, 3, 4] [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

See @Ignacio's answer... much, much safer.

Applying the use of ast would yield:

```
>>> import ast
>>> def myFunc(myString, myList1, myList2):
...     print myString, myList1, myList2
... 
>>> myFunc(*ast.literal_eval("('item 1', [1,2,3,4] , [4,3,2,1])"))
item 1 [1, 2, 3, 4] [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 20):

You're looking for [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("('item 1', [1,2,3,4] , [4,3,2,1])")
('item 1', [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I am running Python 2.3, is this for a later version?  I can't find ast module.

Comment: @Das.Rot: Unfortunately it is.

Comment: @Das.Rot:  Looks like it is 2.6+.  If you are sure about the contents, then `eval` will work.

Comment: OMG, this solves a very important thing for me.  I am using ConfigParser.  I am writing a tuple to a file as one of the arguments for a config setting.  Using this allows me to read back in the string that represents the tuple and convert it back to a tuple.  This is very powerful for creating lists or tuples of data in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to also look at the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module for saving python objects out to text files and then reading them back in.